# how to connect Android phone with Google Glass for data sharing

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I've made my app running on the Google Glass, but it's a little slow in real time. Is there a way to connect my Android phone with the Glass for data communication, so that the phone can take care of the calculation, and the Glass only show the result? The Glass can tether with Android phone by bluetooth, so it should be able to transmit data via it?

Don't know if it's possible to run my app on cloud server and send the result back to my Glass, but guessing that would be slow as well.

Any suggestion is more than welcome! thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can connect your Android phone with Glass for data communication,  to receive internet content for example.  This can be accomplished using Glass to WiFi (but you need the phone to set this up the first time), or Glass to phone to Bluetooth if your phone supports bluetooth tethering, which is often a carrier option.

If you are a Glass explorer this should have been explained when you picked up your Glass, but you can contact the Glass Guides for more information, if you are a Glass Explorer you will have this contact information.  I have found them to be extremely helpful and fun to work with on usability questions.  It doesn't hurt that if you visit them physically they ply you with treats and drinks.

If you are asking if you can open a socket directly between phone and Glass, that is not supported functionality, but you can [request it](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/).  It might be possible when the GDK is made public, but there is no timeline for that.

If you wanted to do calculations on a phone and pass them to glass they would have to go through the cloud, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/overview).  Check out the section titled "How developers interact with Glass" and the accompanying graphic.  I find it to be fast (sub one second with good connectivity), but that is subjective, your speed needs are not well defined in your question.  A consideration is that every round trip of data will count against your API console daily limit, which is 1000 for most everyone.  There is also a 10 request/second limitation.

Last note - there are unsupported ways of talking directly between Glass and a phone for a device you have direct access to, but this is not supported, and could not be used by other Glass users very easily.  The techniques to accomplish this are alluded to in the Google I/O 2013 session: [Voiding Your Warranty: Hacking Glass](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/332704837).

This forum isn't an appropriate one to discuss this, if you were to contact me directly somehow I could give you some pointers in the right direction, but I don't advise this route at all.

Comment: very useful source! Just I need to control phone camera to scan AR code to generate some models, and the Glass should be able to see it in real time. I doubt if that's possible through the cloud. When I directly run the app on Glass, the rendering is slow with a lag when moving the Glass camera. Any idea?

Comment: Correct, augmented reality applications will not work well prior to the GDK, and there is no guarantee they will after either.  Sounds like you have a neat project.  If you thought my response was helpful please up vote it or accept it.