# Stream video to Google Glass from camera over WiFi

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I am interested in streaming live video from an external camera to Google Glass for display. I think WiFi will be required for the data rates. Has anyone tried to do this as yet? I'm thinking of trying this first with a simple security-camera type source like a Y-Cam cube. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) supports Glass since January. I believe that the recent update to 4.4 makes Glass een easier to integrate with an webcam.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried either of these solutions, but they may help you find a workable solution.

1. Since Glass supports Hangout Video Calls, you can have the sending camera initiate one and transmit using this feature. This goes through Google's infrastructure, but it is generally well tuned for bandwidth usage and speed.
2. Timeline cards can carry streaming video as the payload. Depending on your actual requirements, this may be a good way to establish a direct stream of the video without going through Google's servers. See https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline?hl=en#attaching_video for some details.

Comment: It seems unlikely that 1 would work (hard to have the camera join a hangout) but points for creativity.  I think #2 is an awesome idea.  Up voted. It might even work on local wifi depending on how the camera does its streaming.

Comment: @MarkScheel Perhaps, in (1) the author meant an account that initiates a video Hangout to the one Glass is signed in to.

Comment: Answer (1) is moot at this point - Hangout Video Calls aren't supported with the current version of Glass XE (and haven't been for about a year now).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is similar to the answer provided here, which was a related question in some ways:

[how to connect Android phone with Google Glass for data sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023176/how-to-connect-android-phone-with-google-glass-for-data-sharing)

The gist is that external devices have to go through the cloud and can not connect directly with Glass at this time.  An option is to wait for the GDK but there is no timeline and no assurance this feature will be included.  Another option is to follow steps in the hacking glass Google I/O presentation, again, not advised, may not work etc.  A common phrase used in help articles will mention side-loading apk's onto Glass.

This [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=97&q=video&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary) note implies that sending video in the other direction will work in the GDK if you read the last comment closely.

You might enter your own issue requesting this feature in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/).  I didn't see it already posted in a quick scan, but I would think its on the radar.

Answer (score 0):

Google glass can handle streaming mp4 files. I'm not positive it can stream RTSP streams. I would suggest you create an activity with a [`VideoView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) and try it out.
You can also try just opening a web page with an HTML5 video player as the full body of the page and see if you can open that on glass.

Comment: It can do RTSP as well as per https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline?hl=en#attaching_video